# An efficient way to find all SKNodes within a certain distance from a given point?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I want to know which node or nodes cover certain point of the scene I can do either `scene.nodeAtPoint(point)` or `scene.nodesAtPoint(point)`. Is there an efficient way to do something similar with a *circle*?  That is to be able to find all nodes that have their positions within certain distance from a given point.

I need this to be able to handle user taps better.  The scene is rather scarce (not much user-active sprites on it), so there is no need to demand the user to be very precise with tapping.  I want to use some sort a tolerance around the coordinates of the tap and detect the node that is just close enough to tap location.

The best idea that I have so far is to do `nodeAtPoint()` several times: at the location of the tap, and then at various offsets from it (e.g. up, up-right, rigth, ..., up-left).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to put a circle node with physicsBody at the point in question and let SpriteKits Collision Detection find out if the circle and another node collide?

Comment: @jboi, the idea is interesting.  Do you mean that I have to create `SKPhysicsWorld`, implement `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` on a controller, assign `SKPhysicsBody`ies to all involved nodes, and then on a tap-event create a temporary transparent node with physics body of needed shape, and then let SpirteKit to figure it all out and call `didBeginContact` on the scene's `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

Comment: Better would just be to add a circle node and use those only for hit testing. They can either be child modes of the actual visual nodes, or probably better would be the visual nodes are children of the circle nodes.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov why add anything to the scene when you can test against the tap point directly like 0x141E's answer?

Comment: Keep in mind if you already iterate through nodes in game loop, you can exploit this and put your check in there which will avoid another expensive O(n) loop. And ideally you should keep an array of game nodes rather than looping through every node in the scene which could be a UI element for example.

Comment: @Epsilon, because I had (vane) hope that there might be some (almost) out-of-box ways to achieve that.  Iterating through all the nodes and calculate the distances feels a bit over the top, but I think now it's the only way.

Comment: Do GameplayKit's new optimisations for hit testing help with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine if one or more nodes in the scene are within a fixed distance of a touch event, 1) compute the distance between the touch and each node and 2) compare if that distance is less than or equal to a constant. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodes = nodesNearPoint(self, point:location, maxDistance: 30)
        if nodes.count > 0 {
            print("node is near touch point")
        }
    }
}

// Returns an array of all SKNode objects in the subtree that near the specified point.
// If no nodes are near the point, an empty array is returned.
func nodesNearPoint(container:SKNode, point:CGPoint, maxDistance:CGFloat) -> [SKNode] {
    var array = [SKNode]()
    for node in container.children {
        // Only test sprite nodes (optional)
        if node is SKSpriteNode {
            let dx = point.x - node.position.x
            let dy = point.y - node.position.y

            let distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
            if (distance <= maxDistance) {
                array.append(node)
            }
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: You do not need to use sqrt. In fact you will save a lot of cpu time by not using it

Comment: Just compare if the point squared is = to max distance squared

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I thought about doing that, but I thought the answer was clearer with the sqrt.

Answer (score 6):

### Distance

First of all we need an extension to find the distance between 2 `CGPoint(s)`

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(hypotf(Float(point.x - self.x), Float(point.y - self.y)))
    }
}
```

### The closest child

Now we can add an extension to `SKScene` to find the child closest to a given point and within a `maxDistance`.

```
extension SKScene {
    func closestChild(point: CGPoint, maxDistance: CGFloat) -> SKNode? {
        return self
            .children
            .filter { $0.position.distance(point) <= maxDistance }
            .minElement { $0.0.position.distance(point) < $0.1.position.distance(point) }
    }
}
```

### Time

The computational complexity of the extension above is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of direct children of the scene.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to all the answerers, this is what I came up with in the end:

```
extension SKNode {
    private func squareDistanceTo(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let dx = point.x - position.x
        let dy = point.y - position.y

        return (dx * dx + dy * dy)
    }

    func nearestNode(point: CGPoint) -> SKNode {
        return children.minElement() {
            $0.squareDistanceTo(point) < $1.squareDistanceTo(point)
        } ?? self
    }

    func nodesInVicinity(point: CGPoint, tolerance: CGFloat) -> [SKNode] {
        let squareTolerance = tolerance * tolerance

        return children.filter() {
            $0.squareDistanceTo(point) <= squareTolerance
        }
    }
}
```

Above extends `SKNode` with functionality:

- `nearestNode` to find a child node nearest to the specific point, or give back the parent if there's no child nodes.
- `nodesInVicinity` to get an array of nodes that have their positions within certain distance from a given point.

After some test I came to the conclusion that even `nodeAtPoint` has O(n) complexity, hence no hope for quick wins.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've handled this before is to create a circle (using a png of a circle), setting the size to the radius I'm interested in and then seeing what nodes fall in that radius.

This is the basic idea assuming `otherNodes` is an array of the nodes I'm interested in checking:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let radius = 500
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "circle.png"), color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    circle.position = touches.first!.locationInNode(self)

    for node in otherNodes {
        if circle.containsPoint(node.position) {
            //The center of this node falls in the radius
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
After looking at an old solution where I used this, I noticed that `containsPoint` is actually looking to see if the point is within the node's `bounding box`, so having a png of a circle is actually irrelevant and consequently, matches might fall outside of the radius of the circle, but still within its bounding box.

Comment: Yes, png of a circle is still a square, and `containsNode` (or `nodeAtPoint`) are using sprite _frames_ for calculations.

Comment: Basically you enumerating nodes anyway, s this solutions is less efficient than others due to node creation.