# Check if a specific node is near another one SpriteKit, Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game and when an enemy is shot I want to check if there's a protector enemy to take the damage instead of the one shot.

How can I check if there's this type of enemy within a certain distance of the enemy shot ?
I thought about enumerateChildNodes but I should change the name of the protectors and this doesn't help to count them as enemy in many functions

Thank you !

Comment: "to check if there's a protector enemy to take the damage instead of the one shot"  Nobody even knows what a protector enemy is.

Comment: Without fail, El Tomato swoops in with his negative disparaging comment, once again. One day, we shall witness an attempt to answer a question...

Answer (score 0):

Is a "protector" enemy always associated with an enemy? Can you link the two with a `protector` optional property?

If not, you'll need to search using the [radius from the enemy's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474239/an-efficient-way-to-find-all-sknodes-within-a-certain-distance-from-a-given-poin)

Then search that array of nodes for the protector enemy, and pick the first (or one at random) to damage instead.